# Getting a syntax error in React that says Unexpected token, expected "," (49:8)

Tags: reactjs

I'm still fairly new to react and when doing a project for class I got an error at one of my return statements that says:

Unexpected token, expected "," (49:8)

I've tried to place everything into a "div /div" element but nothing changed. I feel as though this problem is something simple that I'm overlooking but I can't find any solutions anywhere and my deadline is coming up quickly.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


export class CourseTable extends Component {
    render() {
        const name = this.props.name;
        const credit = this.props.credit;
        const courses = this.props.courses;

        const rows = [];
        console.log("--- CourseTable ---");
        console.log("Name:" + name);
        console.log("Credit:" + credit);
        console.forEach((c) => {
            console.log("Received a course: " + c.id + " " + c.prefix + " "+ c.number);

            if (c.id === 1) {
                console.log("--course 1 " + c.course);
                rows.push(
                    <CourseRow
                        course={c}
                        key={c.id}
                        editCallback= {this.props.editCallback}
                    />
                );
            }
            if (c.id === 2 && credit < 71)  {
                console.log("--course 2 " + c.course);
                rows.push(
                    <CourseRow
                        course={c}
                        key={c.id}
                        editCallBack= {this.props.editCallBack}
                    />
                );
            }
            if (c.id === 3 && credit > 70){
                console.log("--course 3 " + c.course);
                rows.push(
                    <CourseRow
                        course={c}
                        key={c.id}
                        editCallback= {this.props.editCallBack}
                    />    
                )
            }
        }

        return (
            <table className="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan="7" className="bg-primary text-white text-center h4 p-2">
                            Writing Emphasis for {name}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Semsester</th>
                        <th>Prefix</th>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Grade</th>
                        <th>Editing</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
            </table>
        );    
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the closing `)` after the `forEach` callback function: `});  return`. But I think you have another typo as well. `console.forEach` should probably be `courses.forEach`.

Comment: yep that was it lol thank youuu

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an extra “}” before  the return. Plus I’m not sure what console.forEach is